# Как составить запрос в sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram, sqlite3

Я не могу вставить приходящие мне данные о пользователя в его строчку, которую я выбираю по user_id.

```
def Get_data(self, cookie, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute(f'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO cookies VALUES(?) WHERE 
            user_id = ?', (cookie, chat_id))
```

Консоль выдает ошибку

- return self.cursor.execute(f'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO cookies VALUES(?) WHERE user_id = ?', (cookie, chat_id))
  sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

Возможно запрос неправильный, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества Да конечно, это бот в телеграмме, когда пользователь отправляет мне строку, я ее хочу добавить в столбец cookie, выбирая при это его строчку по его user_id, который заранее известен.

Comment: Если нужен полный код могу его отправить

Answer (score 0):

```py
def Get_data(self, cookie, chat_id):
    cur = self.connection.cursor():
    cur.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO cookies VALUES(?) WHERE user_id = ?', (cookie, chat_id))
    return cur.fetchall()
```